# divide list of elements in scrapy output into seperate rows

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to separate the output from Scrapy into separate lines in an Excel file but I get something like this
[image]

In other words each output from variant id, price and name should be in placed in seperate lines in Excel.

I am using scrapy-xlsx 0.1.1 library to export output to xlsx file (it cannot be in csv).

Please tell me where is the issue.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import ZooplusItem
import re
class ZooplusDeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'zooplus_de'
allowed_domains = ['zooplus.de']
start_urls = ['https://www.zooplus.de/shop/hunde/hundefutter_trockenfutter/diaetfutter']

def parse(self, response):
    for link in response.css('.MuiGrid-root.MuiGrid-container.MuiGrid-spacing-xs-2.MuiGrid-justify-xs-flex-end'):
        items = ZooplusItem()
        redirect_urls = response.request.meta.get('redirect_urls')
        items['url'] = link.redirect_urls[0] if redirect_urls else response.request.url
        items['product_url'] = link.css('.MuiGrid-root.product-image a::attr(href)').getall()
        items['title'] = link.css('h3 a::text').getall()
        items['id'] = link.css('h3 a::attr(id)').getall()

        items['review'] = link.css('span.sc-fzoaKM.kVcaXm::text').getall()
        items['review'] = re.sub(r'\D', " ", str(items['review']))
        items['review'] = items['review'].replace(" ", "")
        #items['review'] = int(items['review'])

        items['rate'] = len(link.css('a.v3-link i[role=full-star]'))
        items['variant_id'] = [i.strip().split('/n') for i in link.css('.jss114.jss115::text').extract()]
        items['variant_name'] = [i.strip().split('/n') for i in link.css('.sc-fzqARJ.cHdpSy:not(.jss114.jss115)::text').extract()]
        items['variant_price'] = [i.strip().split('/n') for i in link.css('div.product__prices_col meta::attr(content)').extract()]

        yield items
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you actually want in your output? Do you want a single row per variant? You are assigning lists to `variant_*` so that is what you are getting in your output.

Comment: thanjs for the answer. My desired output is to have all variant id, variant names and variant prices in seperate lines in zexcel, not as a list of lists (like it is right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store all the variants with common information duplicated, then you need to loop through each variant and yield that separately. You can copy the common information you've already collected and add to that.

In summary replace

```py
items['variant_id'] = [i.strip().split('/n') for i in link.css('.jss114.jss115::text').extract()]
items['variant_name'] = [i.strip().split('/n') for i in link.css('.sc-fzqARJ.cHdpSy:not(.jss114.jss115)::text').extract()]
items['variant_price'] = [i.strip().split('/n') for i in link.css('div.product__prices_col meta::attr(content)').extract()]

yield item
```

with something like

```py
for i in link.css("[data-zta='product-variant']"):
    variant = items.copy()
    variant["variant_id"] = i.attrib["data-variant-id"]
    variant["variant_name"] = "".join(i.css(".title > div::text").getall()).strip()
    variant['variant_price'] = i.css("[itemprop='price']::attr(content)").get()
 
    yield variant
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. PyCharm is giving me an Unresolved reference 'items' error

Comment: @Adrian Does the code work though? Where does it give you the error?