# How to separate product variants into separate rows in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to get information from product cards. The way I do it is to open the page to category, for instance https://www.zooplus.de/shop/hunde/hundefutter_trockenfutter/puppy and I scrape links to product cards and then scrape everything I need from those.

The problem is that all variants are placed in the same row and I want to separate them so instead of having something like this:

[image]

I'd like to get something like this for each product:

[image]

```
import scrapy
import csv

from ..items import ZooplusPCItem

class ZooplusFinalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'zooplus_product_cards'
    with open("links.csv","r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        start_urls = [item['links'] for item in reader]
    #start_urls = ['https://www.zooplus.de/shop/hunde/hundefutter_trockenfutter/puppy']
    base_url = ['https://www.zooplus.de']

    def parse(self, response):
        all_products = response.css('.MuiGrid-root.MuiGrid-container.MuiGrid-spacing-xs-2.MuiGrid-justify-xs-flex-end')

        for product in all_products:
            product_url = self.base_url[0] + product.css('.MuiGrid-root.product-image a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(product_url, callback=self.parse_product)


    def parse_product(self, response):
        for link in response.css('.product__main__page'):
            items = ZooplusPCItem()

            redirect_urls = response.request.meta.get('redirect_urls')
            items['category_url'] = self.start_urls
            items['product_url'] = link.redirect_urls[0] if redirect_urls else response.request.url
            items['category_path'] = link.xpath('//*[@id="js-breadcrumb"]/li/a/span/text()').getall()
            items['title'] = link.css('.pd__title [itemprop="name"]::attr(content)').extract_first()
            items['brand'] = link.css('.pd__title [itemprop="brand"]::attr(content)').extract_first()
            items['review'] = link.css('span[itemprop=reviewCount]::text').extract_first()
            items['rate'] = link.css('span[itemprop=ratingValue]::text').extract_first()


            for i in link.css("[data-zta=productVariants]"):
                variant = items.copy()
                variant["variant_id"] = i.css("div.clearfix[itemprop=offers]::attr(data-variant-id)").getall()
                variant["variant_ean"] = i.css('.product__varianttitle [itemprop=gtin13]::attr(content)').getall()
                variant["variant_name"] = [i.strip() for i in i.css('.article-description::text').extract()]
                variant["variant_price_discount"] = i.css("meta[itemprop=price]::attr(content)").getall()
                variant["variant_price"] = "".join(i.css("span.product__smallprice__text::text").getall()[0]).strip()
                variant["variant_price_per_kg"] = "".join(i.css("span.product__smallprice__text::text").getall()[1]).strip()

                yield variant
```

This is how I save items.

`item.py`:

```
class ZooplusPCItem(scrapy.Item):

    category_url = scrapy.Field()
    product_url = scrapy.Field()
    category_path = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    brand = scrapy.Field()
    review = scrapy.Field()
    rate = scrapy.Field()
    variant_id = scrapy.Field()
    variant_name = scrapy.Field()
    variant_ean = scrapy.Field()
    variant_price_discount = scrapy.Field()
    variant_price = scrapy.Field()
    variant_price_per_kg = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: how you are saving the items? Did you write your code in items.py or you just use the command to dump it into a csv directly?

Comment: @MagedSaeed, I've updated my question and uploaded the code that I have in items.py

Comment: Sorry, I meant the process_item() method in the pipeline.py file. In this method, you can specify how to store the item. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#process_item

Comment: actually I didn't touch pipelines.py at all but I will read about it in documentation

Comment: This method is accountable for storing items. You can specify any logic you want to store. Maybe you can filter out, save to a custom path etc.

Comment: Make sure also you are not getting multiple values when filling items in the spider. If you are sure that you are only getting one value, I do not think you need to override the default process_item() behaviour.

Comment: I thought I answered this problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67485285/divide-list-of-elements-in-scrapy-output-into-seperate-rows ? The code I wrote for that gives me one row per variant. I've not looked closely but I expect it is something with your selectors.

Comment: @tomjn yes the code is working fine but, in this case, I needed to crawl through each product card to get EAN code and the script is putting all variants in the same row (no idea why). That's why I posted this as new question

Comment: @Adrian the problem is in your loop over the product variants. There is only one `[data-zta=productVariants]`. Instead try `for i in response.css("[data-variant-id]"):`

Comment: @tomjn thanks a lot, yeah that was a very silly mistake but it works now. I will remember that in the future.

Comment: @barny I will remember about what you said